# rsync time comparison - what's the precision of the Modified times comparison

Tags: rsync, date

I'm doing some synching with rsync using:

```
rsync --rLvv --times --size-only
```

For my initial sync.  My idea, now is to use:

```
rsync --rLvv --times
```

To synch files that have a new modified time.  My problem is that after the initial rsync, I see the following Modified times on the files that have been synced:

```
remote$ stat 6080_04_big.mp4
  File: `6080_04_big.mp4'
  Size: 258788267       Blocks: 505448     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 862897      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2000/ht)   Gid: ( 2000/    cust)
Access: 2010-08-13 10:46:20.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2010-08-12 17:55:08.000000000 -0700
Change: 2010-08-13 10:46:20.205721673 -0700
```

```
local$ stat 6080_04_big.mp4
  File: `6080_04_big.mp4'
  Size: 258788267       Blocks: 505448     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 902h/2306d      Inode: 136015      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  506/   admin)   Gid: (  506/   admin)
Access: 2010-08-12 20:55:01.482104000 -0400
Modify: 2010-08-12 20:55:08.468122000 -0400
Change: 2010-08-12 21:15:06.952810711 -0400
```

The modify time is 'effectively' the same, but only down to the second.  What's the resolution of the comparison here?  It seems that anything that is the same up to the second is considered the same, but I can't find any docs specifying this.  Anyone know off the top of their heads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the rsync doc (rsync.1.md):

```
0.  `--modify-window=NUM`, `-@`

    When comparing two timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps as being equal
    if they differ by no more than the modify-window value.  The default is 0,
    which matches just integer seconds.  If you specify a negative value (and
    the receiver is at least version 3.1.3) then nanoseconds will also be taken
    into account.  Specifying 1 is useful for copies to/from MS Windows FAT
    filesystems, because FAT represents times with a 2-second resolution
    (allowing times to differ from the original by up to 1 second).

    If you want all your transfers to default to comparing nanoseconds, you can
    create a `~/.popt` file and put these lines in it:

    >     rsync alias -a -a@-1
    >     rsync alias -t -t@-1

    With that as the default, you'd need to specify `--modify-window=0` (aka
    `-@0`) to override it and ignore nanoseconds, e.g. if you're copying
    between ext3 and ext4, or if the receiving rsync is older than 3.1.3.
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad it's in there now!

Answer (score 10):

Here's me answering my own question:

rsync uses the 
utime() call which sets the modification time of a file down to 1 second resolution.  So, effectively, files that are the same up to the second, are considered the same for the time comparison piece of rsync's checks.

Comment: No... i didn't *already* know the answer... I just decided to start digging into the source, since I couldn't find this specified in the docs.

Comment: Bonus points for source-sleuthing.

Comment: Caveat: if the files are stored on FAT filesystems, the resolution is 2 seconds (a limitation of the filesystem). Use --modify-window=1 to avoid odd behavior, which allows for the 2 second discrepancy.

Comment: good call... that could definitely cause a problem.